# Is it possible to set environment variables in a .sublime-project file?

Tags: environment-variables, sublimetext

I'd like some environment variables to be set in Sublime Text when I open the project. This is for the most part just for some plugins that require them to be set.

I believe that there is a feature request for this, but I was still wondering if this isn't possible in some way or another.

http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/103881-sublime-project-should-also-be-able-to-set-environment-variable/

I'm asking this specifically in relation with the GoSublime plugin, for which I'd like to change the GOPATH between projects.

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible just using the project file. You can set environment variables in the `"build_systems"` section of the `.sublime-project` file, but these only take effect when building. If you can [edit] your question with some concrete examples of which plugins you are using, and what values you need to set, I can take a look and see if it might be possible to write an event listener plugin to do what you want to do.

Comment: I'd like to set the GO_PATH variable for the GoSublime plugin, but I really just wanted to know if I was missing something in general. Would think that it was already implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you linked my request to sublime userecho.
Unfortunately nothing really happened over there, so I developed my own plugin to do that.

If you are still interested, please look at this:
https://bitbucket.org/daniele-niero/sublimeprojectenvironment

I have also made a pull request to Package Control to make the plugin available with it.